# How to implement such a function in PHP?

Tags: php, port, reboot

It should test if a specific port is open on localhost,if not,reboot.

It's run in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it, tested on Windows 7 and working. Should work on all NT flavours:

```
function testPort($port, $timeout = 5) {
    if(!fsockopen('127.0.0.1', $port, $errno, $errstr, $timeout)) {
        exec("shutdown.exe /r");
    }
}

testPort(8080);
```

Comment: ...but remember to close it afterwards if this script will be looping around this repeatedly!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a PHP extension to do that. Extension should use Windows API to reboot the machine because the socket checking part can be done straight in PHP. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491887/how-to-write-php-function) is a question on how to write extensions.

[InitiateSystemShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376873(VS.85).aspx) is the Win32 API function you can call to do the actual rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Use sockets 
you need to open a TCP connection (socket) to the localhost with that specific port. If the connection is establish, it means the port is open, otherwise (if timed-out or rejected), then the port is closed.

that's only for TCP ports

[here's a sample code](http://snipplr.com/view/1677/php-socket-client/)

For the 'reboot' part, use [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)[`('shutdown -r');`](http://samanathon.com/windows-tip-shutdown-your-computer-with-the-command-prompt/)